# Assign objects by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, reference

This code works. No errors with php7. But my IDE shows errors. IDE support says to me that this code is not valid. Is this code OK or not ?

```
class A {
    public function hop() {
        echo "hop";
    }
}

function feed(A & $a=null) { //this function assign $a reference to A instance
    $a = new A();
}
feed($a); //$a doesn't exists at this point
$a->hop(); //Say correctly "hop"
```

Comment: does your error go away if you remove the space between the reference operator and your variable? `&$a`

Comment: is your ide php7 aware?

Comment: It's not strictly invalid, but you'll be getting a undefined variable warning.

Comment: Why are you using a reference there? This kind of behaviour is very unidiomatic in PHP, `feed()` making it hard to read. (and the engine doesn't really like references ...)

Comment: I suggest you to define or maybe initialize `$a` with null or something, before calling `feed`. It will be much less surprising.

Comment: @Johannes, it's just a concept example on this form, I use this syntax when the function have many return variables. It was usual in C in my youngest days.

Comment: @Xmanoux C is a very different language. In C using a pointer is cheaper than copy, in PHP a reference often is more expensive than passing by value (due to copy on write and implementation details) for multiple values one can use an array or restructure the code, i.e. OOP paradigms reduce need a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this code OK or not ?

The PHP interpreter itself doesn't throw a syntax error (code wouldn't run) or even a warning, so this is valid PHP code

However, it's bad habit to use a variable without first declaring it, so your IDE is right to bug you when you call `feed($a)` without first declaring `$a=null`;

Comment: You would get a notice though.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and as I mentioned it's not good code. Still, notices are not a sign of invalid code. They're meant to help you write better code. Invalid code triggers fatal errors. I'm responding to the OP who experienced his IDE's support team telling him that "this code is not valid"